# How to set overflow-y to a 100% height container

Tags: css, height, overflow, containers

```
html,body{
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
}
#container{
    height:100%;
    background:red;
}
body>#container{
    height: auto;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

I set a container with those css properties to get a 100% height and it works.
Now i have a lot of **div** in the **#container** like this:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="myClass"></div>
    <div class="myClass"></div>
    <div class="myClass"></div>
    etc.....
</div>
```

so i applied an **overflow-y:auto;** to the **#container** to scroll them when are too many but they go out of the container without show the scrollbar ... i already read other posts about "100% height container and overflow" but is not my case... any solutions?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is what you want, I don't know how many times I've had this problem myself. Make sure you set 100% width on the `<html>` then `min-height` on `body`, and `#container`.

```
   html {
      height:100%;
    }

    body {
      min-height:100%;
    }

    #container {
     min-height:100%;
    }
```